# Java program to insert missing accessibility attributes into the HTML tag

Tags: java, html, accessibility

I need to write a Java program which will insert the missing accessibility attributes in the HTML tag.

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox"/>Check it !!!
    </body>
<html>
```

Now inserting a title will make it accessible, but I don't know what'll be the value of the title. So at least if we can insert the blank `title=""`.

For this specific program I want to do some thing like the ava code will read the HTML file and will search for the input tag and will insert a blank `title=""`.

How do I write the code or can I improve it?

Comment: Find yourself a Java HTML parser and work with that. It will make things nice and possible.

Comment: if you can promise that the code is xhtml, you can use an xml transformation without writing any java code... would need an xsl stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the correct HTML in your case is:

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox"/><label for="chk1">Check it !!!</label>
</body>
<html>
```

Do *not* add title="" to elements, this will likely make them less accessible or cause confusion. Title is a tricky element to use; title text is generally not available to keyboard users (it usually only appears on mouse hover), and screenreaders may treat it inconsistently; some will read it instead of the tag's content, others will read it in addition to it. There are few cases I know of where title is the right solution; stick with using label (as above), using alt on images, and so on.

Comment: Seconding BrendanMcK: Use LABEL, FOR to bind the label to your controls and ID (for JavaScript) 
**LABEL** [http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/label]
**TITLE** [http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/title]

Answer (score 2):

> I need help to write the code or if I can improve it in a better way ?

Adding `title=""` to `<input>` elements is NOT going to improve accessibility.

What you need to do is to manually edit the pages, adding `title` attributes (or whatever) that actually say what the inputs mean.  (Ditto for images, etc, etc.)  There is no magical Java wand that can generate meaningful descriptions out of thin air.

Comment: Agree with the main point here: adding tags mechanically will not improve accessibility; and if anything it may make the page less accessible. Having said that, title is usually not the appropriate tag to use. In the example above, LABEL would be more appropriate. title has problems in that not all screenreaders read it out, or it is not available to keyboard users.